# Displaying a single form field in django templates?

Tags: python, html, django, forms, templates

I only want to create

```
forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)
```

field to create a simple select html item.  Because this is all I want, I don't really want to create a new form class etc.  So is there a way to render only one form field in django templates without creating/passing in a form?

for example:

```
def index(request, template_name="main/index.html"):
    select = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)
    return render_to_response(template_name, locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

is there a way I can do {{ select }} in the django template or something like that to create a select item?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need an entire Django form class, I would recommend just passing the list of choices to the template and iterating over it to create the `<option />` tags for the `<select>`. That's a lot easier than trying to render a form widget at the template level, imo.

Comment: i ended up doing this, but am still curious if a single form field in a template is possible.

Answer (score 0):

only one choices field? why not just write all HTML code into your template and only send the CHOICES dict to your template by using templatetags to handle it.